# Keyboard does not respond when in BIOS menu

Tags: keyboard

I loaded 14.10 along side Windows 7.  When I boot, I see the choices for Ubuntu and Windows in the BIOS boot menu, but the key board arrows doesn't work until after boot-up is complete.  The BIOS defaults to Ubunto.  I first tried it with a wireless keyboard and again with a USB keyboard.  How do I change to windows boot in the BIOS menu if the keyboard is not recognized?

Comment: UEFI BIOS menu or grub menu? (grey/blue/black menu or purple menu?)

Comment: This is a hardware specific problem. Most likely the USB devices aren't being loaded until the operating system boots.

Comment: Seth, how do I correct the problem?

Comment: No support for the USB keyboard? Woah... it had to be really old motherboard. Did you updated BIOS?

Answer (score 2):

I moved the USB keyboard from the front of the computer to one of the ports on the back of the computer. It works now.  Must have something to do with the priority of the ports.